# Eclipse Break on Standard Error Output

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Using the eclipse debugger, is it possible to break whenever something is printed to the Standard Error Output (e.g. `System.err.println("error")`)? I need this because I have a program that prints errors and I would like to know where in the code they were printed.

Comment: You can probably put a conditional breakpoint in `PrintStream.println` with `this == System.err`. Another approach is to use `System.setErr` to set it to a class that extends `PrintStream` so you can put a breakpoint in it.

Comment: Whilst not directly answering your question, you should avoid the use of System.out/System.err in your code. Any of the many logging frameworks would show you exactly where the message came from for free, and would be more user friendly in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a self written stream class [as error stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) at the very start of the program and easily put breakpoints into that class.

Have a look at [this implementation](http://jeeeyul.wordpress.com/2012/10/18/make-system-out-println-rocks/), which even saves you the breakpoints, as it prints out the code location automatically, whenever some output occurs.